# Add and Open Project Folder in Visual Studio Code using ZSH Terminal?

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I am following a series of tutorials to learn command line and, my teacher open and adds the project folder in Atom using the command

```
atom .
```

but she is using bash shell, and I am using zsh (is the default shell macOS has since Catalina) and visual studio code.

I've tried the following commands unsuccessfully:

```
Visual\ Studio\ Code -a   
open -a 'Visual Studio Code'
code .
open Visual\ Studio\ Code .
```

I just want to know what is the equivalent command to her `atom .` but for vs code in zsh.

Comment: The shell shouldn't make any difference. The command is simple: pass the string `.` to the command `atom`.

Comment: I don't know how to translate this to use VS Code instead, but again it's  unlikely to require anything specific to a shell, only commands specific to VS Code.

Comment: Okay, thank you very much your answer give me the idea of what could be my problem.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was that actually I needed to install the `code` command to `PATH` as specified in the official VS Code documentation:

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/mac

1. Launch VS Code.
2. Open the Command Palette (Cmd+Shift+P) and type `shell command` to find the Shell Command: `Install 'code' command in PATH command.`
3. Restart the terminal for the new $PATH value to take effect.

So now you'll be able to type `code .` in any folder to start editing files in that folder, just like in my `atom .` example